# Setting up IPV6 linux router

Tags: linux, router, forwarding

I am trying to setup IPv6 linux router. My setup is as shown below.

HOST1 (eth0) -----(eth0) ROUTER (eth1) ------ (eth0) HOST2

I am trying to ping HOST2 from HOST1. I am actually seeing packets until eth0 interface of ROUTER. But ROUTER is not forwarding those packets via eth1 to reach eth0.

I enabled IPV6 forwarding in router. Is there anything I am still missing out?

Check the ipaddresses of each interface

```
HOST1 (eth0) - link local address
ROUTER (eth0) - link local address
ROUTER (eth1) - 2400:ab::1
HOST2 (eth0) - 2400:ab::2
```

Comment: Are you testing with `fe80::` addresses?

Comment: Not exactly but I am trying to reach from a host with link local address to host2 with global address

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to say without more details...

1. (Even if it sounds ridiculous): Be sure to use an IPv6-ping (Linux: `ping6`)
2. Check if a firewall is in place. If yes: Check if packet forwarding for IPv6 packets is allowed (for TCP, UDP *and* ICMP6 packets)

Comment: 1. I am using ping6 to ping the other end 2. I flushed out all the rules in ip6tables so default option would be forward right ? ..

Comment: Not sure if flushing the tables resets the default policy and I have no Linux box available right now. Just list the rules and check or explicitly allow forwarding with ip6tables -P FORWARD ACCEPT.

Answer (score 0):

[Link-local addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) are local to the *link* (an Ethernet [broadcast domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_domain)), and packets with such addresses are **[forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6) from being forwarded** by routers.

Besides, such addresses are always in the same `fe80::/10` prefix – for both eth0 and eth1 – so even if the packets were forwarded, the *replies* would go to the wrong location.